# PHP - Como receber um fluxo de dados partindo de um post Python?

Tags: php

Eu pretendo carregar uma sessão autenticada de um site usando os cookies enviado por um aplicativo feito em Python nao codificado por mim.

Como mostrado na imagem a abaixo, os dados são enviados via `post` em um fluxo de bytes. A questao é, como receber e tratar esses dados de forma correta para uso na opção `CURLOPT_COOKIE` do `curl` em um script PHP ?

[image: Imagem do código Python]

Desta forma funciona corretamente se usar o arquivo `cookies.txt` localmente.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt'
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Mas desta forma recebendo os cookies por meio de um `post` do Python não carrega a sessão corretamente.

```
$cookiedata = var_dump($_POST);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookiedata,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt'
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Acho que isso é tudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, ler a documentação ajuda muito, ao invés de programar chutando como as coisas funcionam.

Segundo, **é tanto erro em seu código**, logo de cara já dá pra ver que isso está errado:

```
CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'cookies.txt',
```

Porque `CURLOPT_COOKIE` como é descrito na documentação https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php serve para setar os cookies manualmente com uma string, seria o mesmo setar o header `Cookie: foo=bar`, então se está usando o cookie.txt e não pretende setar um valor fixo então nem tem sentido usar isso.

Outra coisa, você usou `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,` e depois `$response = curl_exec($ch);` não faz sentido algum, na documentação está escrito:

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Traduzindo:

> TRUE para retornar a transferência como uma "string" do valor de retorno "curl_exec()" em vez de enviar diretamente para o "OUTPUT".

Agora esse foi o mais errado e sem sentido:

```
 $cookiedata = var_dump($_POST);
```

A função `var_dump` **SEMPRE retorna `NULL`** e só retorna alguma coisa quando usado o segundo parâmetro como `true` assim `var_dump($array, true)`, mas só pra constar, mesmo que retornasse valores **NÃO TEM SENTIDO** usar `var_dump` para passar os valores de POST para os cookies.

Se quer enviar o post como cookies então tem que "fixar" no próprio `CURLOPT_COOKIE`, outra coisa o `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` não é pra manter seus "cookies salvos", seria quase equivalente ao `CURLOPT_COOKIE`, e o que "difere" ele do `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` é que ele o cookie recebe todos cookies e os mantêm para outras requisições futuras, ou seja:

- `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` para setar cookies "fixos"
- `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` para manter cookies setados nas próximas requisições, é salvo quando usado o `curl_close`, pois os cookies podem vir da página requisitada

As pessoas costumar misturar ambos arquivos, o que não faz sentido algum.

Agora para resolver o seu problema, vamos simplesmente explicar por partes, primeiro pegue os valores do POST, você pode iterar e gerar uma string assim:

```
//Um array para receber os POST
$cookies = array();

//Itera o POST
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

     //Adiciona item por item no array no formato "foo=bar"
     if (is_string($value)) {
         $cookies[] = urlencode($name) . '=' . urlencode($value);
     }
}

//Junta todos para o formato aceito pelo header Cookie: foo-bar; abc=123
$cookiedata = implode(';', $cookies);
```

No entanto note que tem uma função mais simples para fazer isto, o `http_build_query`, poderia até usar isto em uma linha só:

```
$cookiedata = http_build_query($_POST);
```

Mas se o payload recebido for algo como:

> user[name]=Bob+Smith&user[age]=47&user[sex]=M&user[dob]=5%2F12%2F1956&pastimes[0]=golf&pastimes[1]=opera&pastimes[2]=poker&pastimes[3]=rap&children[bobby][age]=12&children[bobby][sex]=M&children[sally][age]=8&children[sally][sex]=F&flags_0=CEO

Então vai atrapalhar um pouco a estrutura dos cookies, não muito, mas o suficiente para vai gerar cookies que com certeza não seriam o que você deseja, então por isto usei o `is_string` no `foreach`, claro que não garante muita coisa, mas é o básico.

Segundo, você deve enviar a variável $cookies no `CURLOPT_COOKIE` **apenas**, algo como:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookiedata
]);

$resposta = curl_exec($ch);
```

Terceiro, note que usei `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,` porque isto vai retornar pra variável, mas lembre-se isso será usado se for o que você deseja, se você não quer isto e quer apenas exibir direto então não precisa nem setar, deve ficar apenas isto:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookiedata
]);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Agora uma nota adicional, note que todo e qualquer resposta HTTP pode conter um redirecionamento ou mais, logo o ideal seria definir:

- `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` para redirecionar automaticamente (internamente)
- `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` limita os redirecionamentos, porque a página que esta acessando pode ter algum "bug" que faz redirecionamentos infinitos, um valor talvez ideal aqui seja limitar para 10, mas é apenas sugestão.

Deve ficar:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookiedata,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, //Ativa o redirecionamento
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10  //limita os redirecionamentos para 10
]);
```

Também seria interessante para a maioria dos casos tratar as respostas HTTP, pro seu caso eu não sei, porque é você quem controla a página em python, mas supondo que uma página emita um código diferente do range 2xx então você deveria tratar isto com `curl_getinfo`+`CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE`, exemplo:

```
$resposta_http = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//Qualquer código fora do range 200 e 299 provavelmente é pagina de erro
if ($resposta_http < 200 && $resposta_http > 299) {
    $resposta = false;
}
```

Se deseja pegar o resultado então use desta forma (provavelmente isto é o que deseja, mas não tenho como saber):

```
//Um array para receber os POST
$cookies = array();

//Itera o POST
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

     //Adiciona item por item no array no formato "foo=bar"
     if (is_string($value)) {
         $cookies[] = $name . '=' . $value;
     }
}

//Junta todos para o formato aceito pelo header Cookie: foo-bar; abc=123
$cookiedata = implode(';', $cookies);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookiedata,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  //Pega resposta em uma var
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, //Ativa o redirecionamento
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10  //limita os redirecionamentos para 10
]);

$resposta = curl_exec($ch);

//Verifica se conectou e baixou algo, mesmo que tenha um código HTTP de erro
if ($resposta !== false) {

    //Pega O CÓDIGO da resposta HTTP
    $resposta_http = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    //Qualquer código fora do range 200 e 299 provavelmente é pagina de erro
    if ($resposta_http < 200 && $resposta_http > 299) {
        //Seta false para evitar continuar o processo no proximo IF
        $resposta = false;
    }
} else {
    $resposta_http = 0;
}

curl_close($ch);

if ($resposta) {
    echo $resposta; //coloquei um ECHO mas aqui você pode fazer o que quiser com a resposta
} elseif ($resposta_http > 0) {
    echo 'Ocorreu o erro HTTP: ' . $resposta_http;
} else {
    echo 'Não foi possivel se conectar com o servidor';
}
```